# Proxy with Java and Axis

Tags: java, axis

In my web application, I access two separate APIs using Axis 1.4. I want to use a proxy server with one of them and not the other. Sometimes, the API calls may run simultaneously.

I can do this:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", myProxyIP);  
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", myProxyPort);
```

Or this:

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost", myProxyIP);  
AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort", myProxyPort);
```

But these will set the proxy globally, right? So, multiple threads would be affected. Also, would these calls be thread safe?

Are there any other alternatives? Will [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2295) affect me?

Edit:

Sorry for the multiple questions, but how do I remove the proxy before making the calls that don't require it?

Comment: If one API needs a proxy and the other doesn't, I guess that they point to different servers. Did you consider setting the `http.nonProxyHosts` system property to exclude some target servers while still setting the global proxy?

Comment: @jcoder I tried to simplify the problem for the question. In fact, they point to the same host, but, depending on other parameters, they should or should not use a proxy when making the calls.